# Why do elementary matrices generate the special linear group over polynomial rings?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, gr.group-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. An *elementary matrix* over $R$ is a matrix with $1$s along the diagonal and at most one other nonzero entry. Let $\text{EL}_n(R)$ denote the subgroup of $\text{GL}_n(R)$ generated by the elementary matrices.

I understand that $\text{EL}_n(R) = \text{SL}_n(R)$ provided that $R$ is a Euclidean domain.

Why does $\text{EL}_n(\mathbf{Z}[X_1,\ldots,X_m]) = \text{SL}_n(\mathbf{Z}[X_1,\ldots,X_m])$?

Comment: Don't you also need to add $n\geq 3$?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the "Suslin stability theorem". There is an [algorithmic proof](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0019/stability.pdf) in Park+ Woodburn, "An algorithmic proof of the Suslin stability theorem for polynomial rings."

Comment: As Gjergji Zaimi notes in his comment, Suslin's theorem does require the assumption `$n \geq 3$`.
